# Python and Matlab code significantly slower then C++

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy, optimization

I have to do a speed comparison of a simple program for detrended fluctuation analysis for Python, Matlab and C++. Unfortunately the speed of my Python and Matlab code was about two orders of magnitude slower then I expected. So either is what I read about those languages wrong, or I wrote the code in a very inefficient way.
That's why I'm asking if there are any obvious ways to speed up the code pasted below. You can download the Data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DdDlcpFacINm13TU5td1BQZGc/view?usp=sharing) if you would like to run the code yourself.

Python hrv_dfa module

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import sys
import time


def hrv_dfa(file, version, verbose):
    r_data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=float, count=-1, sep=" ")

    # compute intervals
    RR = RR_intervals_from_data(r_data)
    RRavg = RR.mean(axis = 0)

    y = (RR - RRavg).cumsum(axis = 0)

    if (verbose):
        fig = plt.ion().figure()
        fig.ion()
        fig.plot(y, 'o')
        fig.show()

    N = len(y)

    #window size
    lk = range(5, int(np.floor(N/10)+1))

    E = np.zeros((len(lk), 1), dtype=float)
    tic = time.time()
    for k in range(0, len(lk)):
        window = lk[k]
        Sq_sum = 0

        y_detrended = np.zeros((len(y), 1), dtype=float)
        if (version == 1):
            for i in range(0, N-window, window):

                y_in_window = y[i:i+window]
                x_in_window = range(i,i+window)

                (a, b) = np.polyfit(x_in_window, y_in_window, 1)
                y_regression = np.add(np.multiply(a, x_in_window), b)[np.newaxis]

                y_detrended[i:i+window] = y_in_window - y_regression.T # bylo [i:i+window-1]
        elif (version == 2):
            for i in range(0, N-window):
                #wybor danych z danego okna
                x_in_window = range(i, i+window)
                y_in_window = y[i:i+window]
                #regresja liniowa dla danej probki
                (a, b) = np.polyfit(x_in_window, y_in_window, 1)
                #usuwanie trendu
                if (not (window % 2 == 0)):
                    y_regression = a*(i+window/2+0.5)+b
                    y_detrended[i] = y[i+window/2+0.5] - y_regression
                else:
                    y_regression1 = a*(i+window/2-0.5)+b
                    y_regression2 = a*(i+window/2+0.5)+b
                    y_detrended[i] = (y[i+window/2-0.5] - y_regression1 + y[i+window/2+0.5] - y_regression2)/2
        else:
            print( 'unsupported window version')
            sys.exit([1])

        if (verbose):
            fig.plot(y_detrended, 'bl-')
            fig.show()

        Sq_sum = np.dot(y_detrended.T, y_detrended)
        E[k] = np.sqrt(Sq_sum/N)

    toc = time.time()
    len(E)
    if verbose:
        fig = plt.figure()
    x = np.log10(lk)
    y = np.log10(E)
    if (verbose):
        plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

    (a, b) = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    if (verbose):
        y_all_fitted = a*x+b
        plt.plot(x, y_all_fitted)
    #print lk[0:12]
    (a1, b1) = np.polyfit(x[0:12], y[0:12], 1)
    if (verbose):
        y_short_term_fitted = a1*x[0:12]+b1
        plt.plot(x[0:12], y_short_term_fitted)

    (a2, b2) = np.polyfit(x[12:], y[12:], 1)
    if (verbose):
        y_long_term_fitted = a2*x[12:]+b2
        plt.plot(x[12:], y_long_term_fitted)

    if (verbose):
        plt.show()

    exec_time = toc - tic
    print( "a = %f" % a)
    print( "a1 = %f" % a1)
    print( "a2 = %f" % a2)
    print( "exec_time = %f" % exec_time)

    #plt.show(block=True)
    return a, a1, a2, exec_time


def RR_intervals_from_data(data):
    RR = np.zeros((len(data), 1), dtype=float)
    for t in range(len(data)-1):
        RR[t] = (data[t+1]-data[t])
    return RR


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hrv_dfa(arg[1], arg[2], arg[3])
```

Python test code (runs every sample 10 times and saves results and execution time to csv)

```
import hrv_dfa34 as hrv_dfa
import sys
import csv

def test_hrv_dfa():
    file_numbers = ["100", "101"] #, "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", \
                #"108", "109", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", \
                #"117", "118", "119", "121", "122", "123", "124", "201", \
                #"202", "203", "205", "207", "208", "209", "210", "212", \
                #"213", "214", "215", "217", "219", "220", "221", "222", \
                #"223", "228", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234"]
    prefix = "..\Data\RPeakData"

    file_names = []


    for i in range(0, len(file_numbers)):
        file_names.append(prefix + file_numbers[i] + ".txt")

    for file_number_idx in range(0, len(file_numbers)):
        for test_number in range(0, 10):
            a, a1, a2, exec_time = hrv_dfa.hrv_dfa(file_names[file_number_idx], 1, False)
            with open('fwrite_sw.csv', 'a', newline='') as fwrite_sw:
                writer = csv.writer(fwrite_sw, delimiter=';', \
                                quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                writer.writerow([file_numbers[file_number_idx], a[0], a1[0], a2[0], exec_time])
            #fwrite_sw.write( + " " + a + " " + a1 + " " + a2 + " " + exec_time + "\n")

    for file_number_idx in range(0, len(file_numbers)):
        for test_number in range(0, 10):
            a, a1, a2, exec_time = hrv_dfa.hrv_dfa(file_names[file_number_idx], 2, False)
            with open('fwrite_mw.csv', 'a', newline='') as fwrite_mw:
                writer2 = csv.writer(fwrite_mw, delimiter=';', \
                                quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                writer2.writerow([file_numbers[file_number_idx], a[0], a1[0], a2[0], exec_time])
            #fwrite_mw.write(file_numbers[file_number_idx] + " " + a + " " + a1 + " " + a2 + " " + exec_time + "\n")

    print('\nDone!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_hrv_dfa()
```

Matlab hrv_dfa module

```
function [ alpha, alpha1, alpha2, exec_time ] = hrv_dfa(file, version, verbose)
    % skrypt ładujący dane i uruchamiający poszczególne metody hrv_dfa
    % metoda 1 - stałe okno (obcinana nadmiarowa część próbek)
    % metoda 2 - ślizgające się okno

    fileID = fopen(file, 'r');
    formatSpec = '%f';
    r_data = fscanf(fileID, formatSpec);%cumsum(r_intervals) % << sztuczne dane
    fclose(fileID);
    %save r_data.out r_data -ASCII

    RR = RR_intervals_from_data(r_data);

    RRavg = mean(RR);

    y = cumsum(RR-RRavg);
    N = length(y);

    lk = 5:floor(N/10);
    E = zeros(1,length(lk));

    tic;

    for k = 1:length(lk)

        window = lk(k); 

        Sq_sum = 0;
        y_detrended = zeros(size(y));
        if version == 1
            for i = 1:window:(N-window+1)

                y_in_window = y(i:i+window-1);
                x_in_window = (i:i+window-1)';

                linear_regression_coeffs = polyfit(x_in_window, y_in_window,1);
                a = linear_regression_coeffs(1);
                b = linear_regression_coeffs(2);
                y_regression = a*x_in_window+b;

                y_detrended(i:i+window-1) = y_in_window - y_regression;
            end
        elseif version == 2
            for i = 1:N-window
                x_in_window = (i:i+window-1)';
                y_in_window = y(x_in_window);

                linear_regression_coeffs = polyfit(x_in_window, y_in_window,1);
                a = linear_regression_coeffs(1);
                b = linear_regression_coeffs(2);
                if (~(mod(window, 2)==0))
                    y_regression = a*(i+window/2 - 0.5)+b;
                    y_detrended(i) = y(i + window/2 - 0.5) - y_regression;% +window/2
                else
                    y_regression1 = a*(i+window/2-1)+b;
                    y_regression2 = a*(i+window/2)+b;
                    y_detrended(i) = (y(i+window/2-1) - y_regression1 + y(i+window/2) - y_regression2)/2;
                end

            end
        else
            exit('unsupported window version');
        end

        if verbose == true
            figure(99);
            plot(y)
            hold on;
            plot(y_detrended)
        end
        Sq_sum = y_detrended'*y_detrended;
        E(k) = sqrt(Sq_sum/N);
    end
    exec_time = toc;
    x = log10(lk);
    y = log10(E);
    if verbose == true
       figure(999);
        hold off
        plot(x, y, '.') 
    end
    allRegression = polyfit(x,y,1);
    alpha = allRegression(1);
    beta = allRegression(2);
    y_all_fitted = alpha*x+beta;

    shortTermRegression = polyfit(x(1:12), y(1:12), 1);
    alpha1 = shortTermRegression(1);
    beta1 = shortTermRegression(2);
    y_short_term_fitted = alpha1*x(1:12)+beta1;

    longTermRegression = polyfit(x(12:end), y(12:end), 1);
    alpha2 = longTermRegression(1);
    beta2 = longTermRegression(2);
    y_long_term_fitted = alpha2*x(12:end)+beta2;

    if verbose == true
        hold on;
        h1 = plot(x,y_all_fitted, 'k-',  'LineWidth', 2.5);
        h2 = plot(x(1:12), y_short_term_fitted, 'g-',  'LineWidth', 2.5);
        h3 = plot(x(12:end), y_long_term_fitted, 'r-',  'LineWidth', 2.5);
        legend([h1 h2 h3], {'prosta aproksymująca dla wszystkich lk', ...
            'prosta aproksymująca dla log10(5) <= lk <=log10(16)', ...
            'prosta paroksymująca dla log10(16) < lk'}, 'Location', 'northwest');
        xlabel('log10(lk)');
        ylabel('log10(E(lk))');
        grid on;
        hold off;
    end


    % helper - returns intervals
    function [RR] = RR_intervals_from_data(data)
        RR = zeros(size(data));
        for t = 1:(size(data)-1)
            RR(t) = data(t+1)-data(t);
        end  
    end
end
```

Matlab test code (runs every sample 10 times and saves to csv)

```
file_numbers = ['100'; '101'; '102'; '103'; '104'; '105'; '106'; '107'; ...
                '108'; '109'; '111'; '112'; '113'; '114'; '115'; '116'; ...
                '117'; '118'; '119'; '121'; '122'; '123'; '124'; '201'; ...
                '202'; '203'; '205'; '207'; '208'; '209'; '210'; '212'; ...
                '213'; '214'; '215'; '217'; '219'; '220'; '221'; '222'; ...
                '223'; '228'; '230'; '231'; '232'; '233'; '234'];

prefix = '..\Data\RPeakData';

file_names = [];

for i = 1:size(file_numbers, 1)
    file_names = [file_names; [prefix, file_numbers(i, :), '.txt']];
end

for file_number_idx = 1:size(file_numbers, 1)
    for test_number = 1:10
        [a, a1, a2, exec_time] = hrv_dfa(file_names(file_number_idx, :), 1, false);
        toStore = [str2num(file_numbers(file_number_idx,:)), a, a1, a2, exec_time];
        dlmwrite('fmwrite_sw.csv', toStore, '-append', 'delimiter', ';');
    end
end

for file_number_idx = 1:length(file_numbers)
    for test_number = 1:10
        [a, a1, a2, exec_time] = hrv_dfa(file_names(file_number_idx, :), 2, false);
        toStore = [str2num(file_numbers(file_number_idx,:)), a, a1, a2, exec_time];
        dlmwrite('fmwrite_mw.csv', toStore, '-append', 'delimiter', ';');
    end
end

display('Done!');
```

Comment: If you divide your code into smaller functions you could use the profiler to get more detailed performance metrics.

Comment: How did you predict how long it would take the python and Matlab code to execute? That's not easy, and is implementation dependent. It's not straightforward to say "I expect this code to take this long"

Comment: @texasflood I read that python is about 30 times slower then C++. So I expected to see faster execution times based on the C++ program.

Comment: If the code works but is slow then maybe this belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use the profiler in Matlab to find out what's taking the most time. Repeatedly calling `dlmwrite` like that is inefficient, for a start.

Comment: @nkjt I know, but i'm not timing it, the hrv_dfa function is  returning the execution time of the part which interests me, between the `tic` and `toc`.

Comment: @Stuart you are probably right, didn't know that it exists.

Comment: @Lukasz `tic/toc` is not the best way to measure, use the actual profiler and you'll get much more of an idea.

Comment: Suggest splitting this question up (and cross-linking) so python people can answer python part and matlab people can answer matlab part

Comment: Your Python code has (at least) 2 for loops - that is wrong if you are concerned with speed.  You want `numpy` to do those iterations in compiled code.  So no - you cannot simply copy a C++ style of coding and expect speed in these languages.  There are many SO questions about 'vectorizing' numpy code.  Not so many on CR.